# Freetypes' parameter.color doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, fonts, libgdx, freetype

In the game I'm making I'm rendering text on screen and I'd like to have white text with a black border but it doesn't seem to let me change the foreground and border colours to what I want.

This is how I create my fonts using a class I made called Font:

```
public BitmapFont font;

public Font(String fontName, int size, boolean border)
{
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.local("font/"+fontName)); // Load in .ttf

    // Custom font settings
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = size;
    parameter.spaceX = 1;
    if (border)
    {
        // Must fix this!!!
        parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
        parameter.borderColor = Color.BLACK;
        parameter.borderWidth = 1;
    }
    this.font = generator.generateFont(parameter);

    generator.dispose();
}
```

Here is how I've initialised the font in my HUD class:

```
arial24 = new Font("arial.ttf", 24, true);
arial24.font.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

And this is how I've rendered it:

```
arial24.font.draw(Game.getBatch(), message, Game.getCamera().position.x - 80, Game.getCamera().position.y + 75);
```

[I expect it to output something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxD6O.png)

[But instead it comes out like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL0XK.png)

Everything seems right according to the github pages and I've been searching through forums for hours and I just can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
arial24.font.setColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

Why are you blending to black if you want white? Just delete this line or change it to

```
arial24.font.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it was so obvious but I couldn't see it at all. It was just one of those times when I needed a fresh pair of eyes to look at it. Thank you for your help.